# ValueError could not convert string into int: Jupyter Python Error

Tags: python, jupyter

I am getting this error when trying to read from a `.csv` file with fields in both integer and string format. 
Error message is as follows,

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent
>   call last)
>        in ()
>             2 FN0 = 'uci-news-aggregator'
>             3 with open('%s.csv'%FN0, 'rb') as fp:
>       ----> 4     id, title, url, publisher, category, story, hostname,timestamp = 
>       pickle.load(fp)
>
> ```
> ValueError: could not convert string to int
> ```

Comment: Why are you using `pickle` if it's a CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, there's a pretty good `csv` package in the stdlib that will help you for that job.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv

Why are you trying to use `pickle`. It cannot work.